# why width property is changin when changing the padding property in html

Tags: html, css

In my assignment I have used div tags.In one div tag I have define following.
When I changing the padding ,It is also changing the width.But I want change only the padding without changing the with of my div class="top-center".
This is the css class

```
.top-center {
    border:1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    height:31%;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 1px;
    border-left:1px;
    border-right: 1px;*/
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-right: -40px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left:20px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color:#ffe0b3 ;
}
```

This is the corresponding div tag

```
<div class="top-center">
    <p class="font-new" id="eff">Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text .</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard box-model behavior. To keep borders and padding from affecting the element width, use `box-sizing: border-box` on the element. Here is a good explanation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

> `border-box` - The width and height properties include the content, the padding and border, but not the margin. This is the box model used by Internet Explorer when the document is in Quirks mode. Note that padding and border will be inside of the box e.g.  .box {width: 350px; border: 10px solid black;} leads to a box rendered in the browser of width: 350px. The content box can't be negative and is floored to 0, making it impossible to use border-box to make the element disappear.

The default box model `box-sizing` value is `content-box`. Here is an explanation for why your box is behaving the way it is currently.

> `content-box` - This is the initial and default value as specified by the CSS standard. The width and height properties are measured including only the content, but not the padding, border or margin. Note: Padding, border & margin will be outside of the box e.g. IF .box {width: 350px;} THEN you apply {border: 10px solid black;} RESULT {rendered in the browser} a box of width: 370px.

Answer (score 0):

Use `box-sizing: border-box` for the div. As padding increases the element width. And also do not use negative values for padding because it is invalid.